# Can I delete the typescript git clone after installation?

Tags: typescript, git, npm, installation

I just installed Typescript with its compiler by using this instructions:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript

My doubt is if I can delete the Typescript git clone or the compiler use information from this directory even after the installation was successful completed. (My SO is Manjaro just in case it is needed)

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you are building TS from source instead of just installing it via npm or your distro's package manager?

Comment: Hello. Thanks your time on responding. I installed Typescript via npm by following the indications of the above link but after that it also teaches how to build the compiler. I am pretty new on this so I just used the first official documentation web browser gave to me.

Comment: Ok, you should just need to follow the directions for "Installing" and not for "Building". The latter would be more for if you want to help develop the TS compiler.

Comment: Ok I see. I suppose I can delete it then. Thanks!